# How to include a modified third-party library in Android?

Tags: java, android, classpath, dex

In my Android project I'm using [barcodescanner](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner).

I need to customize the size of the framing rectangle displayed when targeting a qr code and I noticed that the only way to achieve this is to modify a class in the library.

Now I'm wondering, what is the best way to include the changes I made to the library?

It would be great if I could simply include the class with the original package in my sources as I used to do in some java projects, however in Android I get an error:

```
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lme/dm7/barcodescanner/core/ViewFinderView;
```

because it finds 2 classes with the same signature (1 in the library and 1 in my source code).

Is there a way to avoid this conflict? Or are there better ways to include the 3rd party library with the changes?

Comment: Quick answer without doing all the legwork to explain it all like I should: Fork the repo, make the changes and push them to your fork, then point gradle to your fork.

Comment: I guess I need to include the built forked libs (=aar files) in my project, unless I publish the artifacts to some repository. Correct?

Comment: Is there no way you can simply extend the classes and override their behavior?

Comment: Unfortunately no... I would need to modify and import in my project 4 classes just to change the value of a private static final constant... I'm trying to understand if there is a cleaner and easier-to-maintain way than doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Git clone the library project to your computer, make all the changes you need, then add it to you project as a library module:

```
New module -> import gradle project
```

Mark it a module dependency for your app module:

```
Open module settings -> dependencies -> add module dependency
```

Remove old dependency from build.gradle to avoid

> multiple dex files define ...

error.